# Migration to spring-boot 3.2.0

Tags: spring-boot

we recently upgrade our app from 3.1.2 to 3.2.0 and security stop working, all rest requests return 500. App also using for security 3th part library which is still running on spring-boot 3.0.13. Is spring-security-6.0 is compatible with spring-boot 3.2.0?

Migration from 3.1.2 to 3.2.0

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the details of the errors you're getting (stacktraces from the app log, etc).